# HerokuにDjangoアプリをデプロイ後、Local環境では反映されていた画像が反映されない。

Tags: python, django, heroku

HerokuにDjangoアプリをデプロイ後、Local環境では反映されていた画像が反映されない。

Herokuでデプロイの時、

```
   ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==306 (from versions: none)
   ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==306
```

とエラーは出るが、実際のアプリは画像の反映以外の機能は機能している状況です。
Cloudinaryを使用しています。

Comment: 質問文の状態では「どのように画像を表示させようとして」「どのような結果として反映されていない状態になったか」が掲載されておらず、回答する側も推測すら難しい状況になっています。
質問を編集して「【画像の反映】のために行った実装」「実際のレスポンスやブラウザ上の挙動（ローカル/Herokuで差異があればそれも）」などを追記すると判定材料が増えて回答しやすくなるかもしれません。